# What is the difference between performing a procedure on a resource and performing a state transformation?

Tags: api, rest, web

I'm new to web development and I'm attempting to understand REST. The tutorial I'm watching makes mention of the difference between "procedures" and "state transformation". Stating that REST is based on the notion of "state transformation", but it does not delineate the difference between the two.

This has left me wondering what is the difference between the two? Why can't an operation which transforms the state of a resource also be considered a procedure? After all, 'procedure' sounds like a generic enough term that it would also encompass an operation that would transform the state of a resource.

So, what is the difference between performing a procedure on a resource, and performing a state transformation? Or is it merely a matter of semantics?

I have also tried searching for the answer but can't seem to find anything that will shed light on this.

Comment: "State transformation" is odd... could it have been "state transfer" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

- RPC focues on sending a payload containing method names and arguments in a predefined format. Clients couple tightly to servers through a shared interface (Skeletton classes, WSDL or other interface definition languages (IDLs))
- REST focues on decoupling clients from servers and on introducing indirections, like support of multiple different media types to marshal resource state in, and the whole interaction concepts summarized by HATEOAS where hypertext controls are used to drive the application state forward through a domain application protocol / state machine on the server side. Responses usually contain semi-structured data, which usually don't go well with simple CRUD application, that follow the definition of corresponding media type definition (i.e. the HTML spec). If you will the state of a resource is transformed into a representation format adhering to the rules in the media type definition and transferred to the remote side

---

In network programming, remote procedure call (RPC)-style invocations, i.e. often used in RMI, Corba, SOAP or similar frameworks, will send usually a method name that should be invoked at the server alongside with parameters to feed the method with. The return value is then marshalled into corresponding response and sent back to the caller. What a client could invoke is usually exposed via external stuff, i.e. skeletton classes, WSDL- or other form of contracts and so on. So far, so simple. This is how most of the networking stuff works. However, the drawback here is that a client is tightly coupled to the exposed interface (skeletton classes, WSDL, external documentation) and many problems in internet computing arise due to changes over time that are not adequatly depictable in those interfaces.

If you take a closer look though at how the Web works for decades, change is an inherent part of it. Your browser will just show the most recent state of a resource (Web page) it has. It might eigther got it from its cache or from a server it asked for. If the version available in its cache is older than a predefined threshold value it will ignore the cached value and request a new version. If there happened an update since the last version your browser is automatically served with the new version. Fielding, who was working on the HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 spec back then, analyzed how the interaction on the Web takes place and generalized his findings into the REST architecture design. So, if you will, REST is just *Web surfing for applications*.

Unfortunately a mojority of enthusiasts and professional have not yet understood what REST really is and there is so much false information available in regards to REST, even here at Stackoverflow most people don't seem to care actually and posts explaining the true nature of REST are downvoted and wrong information upvoted.

So, what does REST different than typical RPC-like method invocations?

First, REST relies on a certain set of uniform interfaces, that are the same for every participant in that architecture. These are i.e. HTTP as transport layer and a naming scheme for resource (URI) so that everyone acts on these fixed principles. This helps to reduce interoperability issues that are just way to common in traditional network programming.

Next, it relies on a basic principle: *Servers teach clients what they need to know*. But how does a server know what a client need to know? Well, as [Jim Webber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=191s) pointed out, the designer of the application develops a state machine (or domain application protocol) a client will follow through. Think of a checkout system on your favorite online shop. At one point it presents you the items in your trolly and offers you a choice to progress to the next "page" where you can enter the shipping address and on further progressing through the state machine you will be asked for your payment options and so on until at one point to finished the checkout and are served with a "Thank you" page that summarizes your order. Under the hood you just progressed through their protocol on how to place orders and used application controls to progress your client further through their state machine. You therefore got served with some Web forms and links that you used to fulfill your task. In essence, this is what *Hypertext as the engine of application state* (or HATEOAS for short) is all about.

On the Web [HTML forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html) are used to teach a client about what properties a resource supports, which ones are editable and so on. Besides that, it also teaches clients on the actual URI to send input data to, the HTTP operation to utilze as well as, mostly implicitly given, the media type to marshal the request into. I.e. a regular HTML form will use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as its default media type to send the data to the server. So a full HTTP request for an input of a first and last name may look like this:

```
POST /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1
Host: acme.org
Connection: close
Accept: */*
User-Agent: ...
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 32

firstName=Roman&lastName=Vottner
```

The same data could be sent using a different representation format, if it were supported by the media type the form was issued for. Unfortunately, [HTML does not support that many](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-enctype).

Links provided by a server should usually be annotated (or accompanyied) by so called *link relation names*  that put the current resource in relation with the given URI. If you will they are the predicate in a tripple of subject (current page), predicate (link relation name) and object (link target resource). Such names, of course, should be [standadized](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or at least follow the [Web linking extension mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2). URIs itself are opaque, meaning they themselves don't provide meaning and should therefore not get parsed and analyzed at all. A common mistake often seen in so called "REST APIs" is that they have [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html), i.e. a user resource or a car resource that can be marshalled on the client side to a programming language specific object (i.e. Java object of class `User` or the like) that is pretty common in traditional RPC-sytle programming. In a REST architecture the representation format however is usually semi-structured data, i.e. a mix of syntax defining control inputs or elements and actual data. As such, a direct mapping from DB-Entry, to Model-Object to a resource itself, as done by so many CRUD applications, is not possible.

Why is this all done in first place?

If you compare traditional network programming a client is usually only able to work with that one server and if something at that server changes clients may be affected and thus stop working. There is a tight coupling between those two apparent. The REST architecture introduces a couple of indirections, i.e. usage of link relations instead of attempting to analyze meaningful URIs as well as usage of a multitude of possible media-types instead of relying on a specified version format, which help to decouple clients from servers. I.e. instead on coupling to the server in regards of the message exchanged, both, client and server couple to media types. Through content-type negotiation a client simply tells the server of its capabilities and the server should generate a response the client can process. Instead of focusing on one message format, REST has the freedom of almost infinite ones as long as both, client and server, support these. The more media types a peer supports, the more likely it will be to interact with other peers in that network.

All these points I've mentioned above lead to a strict decoupling of client and servers, which grant the latter one to evolve freely without having to fear that changes introduce will break clients as neither the transport protocol nor the naming scheme have changed and the changes introdcued are still in scope of the media-type definition. So, well-behaved peers in that network will be able to pick up changes on the fly automatically. This is especially handy if you develop an application that should withstand the sands of time and still server clients in years to come.

If you don't need such properties, there is nothing wrong with not being "RESTful" at all, just don't call such services/APIs REST then. Also, developing REST is for sure more overhead compared to typical RPC-style interactions.